# How to run program on vxsim in torando(VxWorks)?

Tags: tornado, vxworks

As I'm new to tornado (VxWorks) tool . To execute program  I did  c program on editor ->compile->build project->Vxsim->shell->main so I need to get output on vxsim 
but when i type main in shell I'm getting one more vxsim .my question is how to solve this problem or if I'm wrong do correct me .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the Windriver VxWorks emulator up?
[image]

If so, you should first find out what directory vxWorks is reading from.
To do this, type `pwd` to find the current working directory.

Once you know this path,
navigate to that directory and put in the binary program you want to run.

*It should be noted, that your binary should have been built for the simulator and not any other kind of architecture.
[image]

Once you know you've built it correctly and the binary exists in the right directory, type `ls` to make sure you can see it in the simulator.

From there, you type `ld < program.out` to load the program into memory.
You can now spawn your entry function.
`sp StartFunction`.

You'll know if the binary you tried to load was built for the wrong architecture, and not the sim if you see something like this:

```
-> ld < main.out
ld(): error loading file (errno = 0x610001).
value = 0 = 0x0
->
```

I'm using WindRiver as well, but not specifically Tornado.  Hopefully the build steps are similar.  Everything you need to type in the simulator should certainly be the same.